# Collectionview inside multiple tableview cells, how to handle selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableview, consisting say, 10 cells.. *Each* tableview cell has a collectionview inside it,

I handle each collectionView's selection's style change by overriding `isSelected` this code

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet{
        if(isSelected){
            backgroundColor = .black
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .red
        }
    }
}
```

It works at this point.. But when i scroll the tableview, i see that selection style (.red) is applied on different collection views that in other cells as well ( because of reuseable cell of course )

I want to keep selection stickied to the collectionview that has a selection inside it, and avoid selection applied on other collectionviews as well

first you see that collectionview has a selected item inside
[image]

when i scroll, i find another dequeued collectionview, with the same selection !, the selection was only at indexpath row 1 not row 5
[image]

Comment: Hey, why you are setting collectionview inside of tableview. You can try collectionview it self. Use section in colleaction view. And set multiple selections enabled. It’s better to manage your problems.

Comment: @Kathiresan.M I have a horizontal collection inside tableview, much like appstore's homepage, where u have a section of games for example then a collectionview inside that has horizontal list of games, the problem happens when i scroll the tableview that data is messed up

Comment: AppStore was developed from collectionview it self

Comment: Using collectionview or tableview as the main vertical scrolling area isn't the issue, either way, the problem is with reusing the collectionview that is inside whether tableview's cells or colletionview's

Comment: My suggestion is if you use collectionview it’s more helpful for you

Comment: This is not going to fix my issue

Comment: Share your design

Comment: Edited with screenshots.

Comment: It’s simple use collectionview

Comment: So use collectionview, and each collectionview cell will contain another collectionview, this will result with same problem, i have a collectionview inside tableview ( 5 collectionviews inside 5 tableview cells)

Comment: Single collectionview with 5 sections

Comment: I want horizontal collectionview inside these 5 sections.. not gonna be single collectionview

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is added a variable named selectedIndex in the modelData.

Check the condition in cellForRowAt and modify the selectedIndex variable on didSelect method